# Refactored code for updating user password, email and other info

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have to update user email and password if they are present in the params, I have other user information also which can be updated.

this is the method I have written, but it doesn't seem like a good method

```
def update
    if user_params[:current_email].present?
      if @current_user.has_valid_email?(user_params[:current_email])
        @current_user.update(email: user_params[:new_email])
      else
        render json: {errors: ["Current Email did not match!"]}, status: :unprocessable_entity and return
      end
    end
    if user_params[:current_password].present?
       if @current_user.has_valid_password?(user_params[:current_password])
        @current_user.update(password: user_params[:new_password])
      else
        render json: {errors: ["Current Password did not match!"]}, status: :unprocessable_entity and return
      end
    end
    if @current_user.update(sanitized_params)
      @web_user = @current_user
      render :show
    else
      render json: {errors: @current_user.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end




private

  def sanitized_params
    user_params.slice!(:current_email,:new_email,:current_password,:new_password)
  end

  def user_params
    params.permit(:current_email, :new_email, :current_password, :new_password, :password_confirmation, :reminders_frequency,
                  :coaching_style, :coaching_style_status,:suggestion_preference,:language,:region)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

A few obvious things would be:

1) You shouldn't include current_email and current_password in the sanitized_params since you don't want to update these only validate them.

2) Similarly for new_email and new_password, you have aleady updated these manually

3) So really you aren't updating anything else currently.

4) If your first two tests fail you render a json error but don't stop processing so the last if clause will still execute and you will get a double render error. You should probably test all your conditions before executing any code.

I would consider moving the update logic into methods on the User model (`update_email`, `#update_password` that do the validation for you.